Why my code that select two variables from a data.table does not work
I have a data.table called data, which has variables CDID and A9ER + some other vars.
I run a simple code:
variable <- 'A9ER'

data <- data[, c('CDID', variable)]

which results in data turns into chr[1:2] "CDID" "A9ER"
while if I do
data <- data[, c('CDID', 'A9ER')]

I get data is data.table with 2 vars?
What am I doing wrong in the first case? Should not the result be the same
I am writing a function that selects the variable CDID and one other variable of my choice among 4054 variables. I got stuck with the first step which does not actually select variables that I want, but wipes out the whole dataset and makes it a character.

Two ways to solve your problem:
# solution 1: using double dot (..)
data[, c('CDID', ..variable)]

# solution 2: using data.table programming interface
data[, c('CDID', variable), env=list(variable = I(variable))]


A bit more in line with data.table's design: data[, .(CDID, ..variable)].

@FrankHarrell Sorry I missed your comment. Note that your code would not return the expected output. .. pattern within .(...) is not interpreted as a special variable carrying column name(s). Your code would create a data.table with two columns whose names are c("CDID", "..variable") where the column named ..variable is of type character with value "A9ER" in all rows. So, .(..variable) and c(..variable) have different meaning. Hope the following example makes it clear: variable = "cyl"; data = as.data.table(mtcars); data[, .(mpg, ..variable)]; data[, c("mpg", ..variable)].

Sorry I thought I had tested that.  Are you using the latest version of data.table?

Yes, I am using data.table 1.15.4, which is currently the most recent version on CRAN.

Here are two alternatives:
DT[, .SD, .SDcols = c("CDID", variable)]
DT[, mget(c("CDID", variable))]

